# When is the spin group a universal covering?

Tags: covering-spaces, spin-geometry

The double covering
$$
\text{Spin}(n)\to SO(n)
$$
is the universal covering for $n\geq 3$ because $\pi_1(SO(n)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ in this case. Analogously,
$$
\text{Spin}(1,n)\to SO^+(1,n)
$$
is the universal covering for $n\geq 3$ because
$$
SO(1,3)\cong SO(1)\times SO(n)\times\mathbb{R}^{n}
$$
has the same fundamental group of $SO(n)$.

**Are these the only signatures when the $\text{Spin}(s,t)\to SO^+(s,t)$ is the universal covering?**